How to handle external dependencies like datetime.now() in FastAPI tests?
I have some existing FastAPI tests which no longer pass, because some internal server logic has changed such that there is now a dependency on a value returned by datetime.now().
This is an external dependency. Normally to handle external dependencies, we would write a mock implementation of the external dependency and find a way to inject it into the code being tested.
I am not sure if that is the best approach for something as simple as a datetime dependency. It might be, or it might not be.
Here is some MWE code which illustrates the problem:
# lib_datetime.py

from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timezone

def now() -> datetime:
    return datetime.now(timezone.utc)

# fastapi_webserver.py

from fastapi import FastAPI

from lib_datetime import now

from datetime import datetime

app = FastAPI()

@app.get('/datetime_now')
def datetime_now():
    the_datetime_now = now()
    the_datetime_now_str = the_datetime_now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f %z')
    return {
        'datetime_now': the_datetime_now_str,
    }

# test_fastapi_webserver.py

from fastapi.testclient import TestClient

from fastapi_webserver import app

from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timezone

client = TestClient(app)

def test_fastapi_webserver_datetime_now():

    datetime_now = datetime(year=2024, month=7, day=20, tzinfo=timezone.utc)
    datetime_now_str = datetime_now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f %z')

    response = client.get('/datetime_now')
    print(response.json())
    assert response.status_code == 200
    assert response.json() == {
        'datetime_now', datetime_now_str,
    }

The problem should be fairly obvious. The value of the datetime returned varies depending on when the test is run. No good.
Here is a summary of what I have tried to fix it:

Monkeypatching. I tried to change what lib_datetime.now() points to from within the test file. I couldn't figure out how to make this work.
Hoisting external dependencies. In theory, now() could depend on an object. Or it could become an object. We could create two objects, one which returns the current datetime, and one which returns a fixed value for testing. I could not figure out how to inject that into the FastAPI app, or even if this is possible. This would be my prefered approach as it is what I am most familiar with.
Use an environment variable to change the runtime behaviour of now(). Again, I was not sure how to integrate this into the test code, and I am not sure this is really a good approach.

The blocker here is that I am not that familiar with FastAPI, as I only recently started using it. So I don't know what I can do with it, yet.

Have you looked into freezegun? https://github.com/spulec/freezegun

@MatsLindh thanks for the tip, that looks like a good solution, however it would be good to know how to do it in general in the context of fast API

If you want to create something similar in your own application where you control the dependencies, you can send in a Clock-type object (that you define yourself) with a now method. You can then override this dependency through FastAPIs regular override_dependencies - and have this dependency be invoked when creating the service that need the clock (so you have Depends calls that return a real clock or a testing clock). However, freezegun has worked great for our use cases, and is portable across projects.

@MatsLindh That doesn't look right. Seems as if overrride_dependencies is to do with FastAPI endpoints which depend on some parameters. That's not the situation here. https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/testing-dependencies/

I think that is just the given particular example, but you can override any function with any other function, see here https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/testing-database/?h=overri#dependency-override

@FreelanceConsultant Correct; anything in FastAPI starts with an endpoint request (and your clock test above is one such GET request). You asked what mechanisms FastAPI has for dynamically changing dependencies, and using Depends is the way. You'd have a Depends(get_foobar_service), where get_foobar_service would have get_foobar_service(clock = Depends(get_clock_object)) (with typing and Annotated added); you could then override get_clock_object when you're in a test context with override dependencies.

Here is a summary of some things I have learned, along with some example code which might be useful for someone else in future.

Do not use Depends
FastAPI has a dependency injection framework which relates to the Depends concept. Do not use this for a global concept such as a call to datetime.now(). It will not work in this context
The Depends concept provides a way to resolve dependencies from within a FastAPI path (endpoint) definition
The catch here is the dependency resolution framework only works at the top level
If you add a Depends type of dependency for something global like a datetime.now call, this will not work from other areas of code
Any depdendencies you want to resolve correctly from elsewhere in your code must be passed as arguments, everywhere
Passing a global thing like a log or now() function is not a good design

Instead roll your own dependency resolution code:
lib_datetime/
    __init__.py
    fake_datetime.py
    real_datetime.py

# lib_datetime/__init__.py

from lib_datetime.real_datetime import now as now_real
from lib_datetime.fake_datetime import now as now_fake


datetime_implementation_is_fake = False

def set_use_fake_now_implementation(use_fake_implementation: bool) -> None:
    global datetime_implementation_is_fake
    datetime_implementation_is_fake = use_fake_implementation

def now() -> datetime:
    if datetime_implementation_is_fake:
        return now_fake()
    else:
        return now_real()

# lib_datetime/fake_datetime.py

from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timezone


current_datetime = None

def now() -> datetime:
    if current_datetime is None:
        raise RuntimeError(f'datetime not set')
    return current_datetime

def set_current_datetime(current_datetime_value: datetime) -> None:
    global current_datetime
    current_datetime = current_datetime_value

# lib_datetime/real_datetime.py

from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timezone


def now() -> datetime:
    return datetime.now(timezone.utc)

To use it:
# normal code:

from lib_datetime import now

current_dateime = now()

print(current_datetime)

# tests

from lib_datetime import set_use_fake_now_implementation
from lib_datetime.fake_datetime import set_current_datetime

current_datetime = datetime(
    year=2024, month=1, day=1,
    hour=9, minute=30, second=0,
    tzinfo=timezone.utc,
)
set_current_datetime(current_datetime_value=current_datetime)
set_use_fake_now_implementation(True)

